# Magento 1.9: Get currency symbol?

Tags: magento-1.9

i tried get symbol but it just show â‚¬

```
$currency_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way of Magento 1.9 to get currency symbol, you are doing it correctly:

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
```

If you are getting unusual currency symbol then check the symbol on backend:

1. Open Magento admin panel, go to System – Manage Currency -> Symbols.
2. Uncheck "Standard".
3. Add a new symbol which you need
   [image]
4. Click "Save Currency Symbol" in the right corner.
5. Clear cache and check on frontend